# Get element by tag name with event.target

Tags: javascript

How do I get the first child `<li>` of a `<span>` in the click event of the span in javascript using `event.target`

Comment: is jquery acceptable?

Comment: Could you show your html structure ?

Comment: HTML forbids `<li>` as children (or even descendants of any kind) of a `<span>` element. Try writing real HTML first.

Comment: Javascript is proffered

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript (a bloated bit of overkill for this particular problem, but still JavaScript).

Comment: In my case, I couldn't figure out any working selector that would get the next element (a div following an anchor), so I just used the expression `el.nextSibling`, where el is the anchor element. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

```
var aEl = event.target.querySelector('a')
```

```js
//Using jQuery
$(".jq").click(function(event){
  var aTag = event.target.querySelector("a");
  console.log(aTag.innerHTML);
  return false;
});

//Using vanilla Javascript
function clicker(event){
    var aTag = event.target.querySelector("a");
    console.log(aTag.innerHTML);
    return false;
}

document.querySelector("span.vanilla").addEventListener("click",clicker,false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="jq">
Using jQuery
<a href="#">First jQuery Link</a>
<a href="#">Second Link</a>
</span>
<br/><br/><br/>
<span class="vanilla">
Using only Javascript
<a href="#">First Vanilla jQuery Link</a>
<a href="#">Second Vanilla Link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry...it was `<a>` not `<li>`

Comment: Ah.. That makes sense.. edited answer. Please update the question too :)

Comment: But I am getting this
`event.target.querySelector is not a function`

Comment: Have included a sample working snippet for your reference. Try running it and see the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

On script

```
<script>
    function myFunction(elmnt) {
        var li = elmnt.querySelector('a:first-child');        
    }
</script>
```

On HTML

```
    <span  onclick="myFunction(this)">

   <a href="#">Sampe1</a>
    <a href="#">Sample2</a>

    </span>
```